# Getting intersecting hexagons from ranges

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I've written a function to get hex grid positions based on a position and range. And from that I've compared two lists for identical grid positions and considered those that match as "intersecting". A visual example:

[image]

The green tiles being the intersecting tiles of two areas.

I then wanted to do this without generating two lists and iterating to find matching tiles, because its not very efficient.

So i tried following this guide:
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#range-intersection

But i am really struggling to understand the logic in that part of the guide so i can write it in code.

This is my method for finding tiles within a given range which was derived from the same guide.

```
    public static int GetHexesInRange(Vector3 gridPosition, int range, List<Vector3> results)
    {
        if (range < 1)
            return 0;

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = -range; i <= range; i++)
        {
            for (int j = Mathf.Max(-range, -i - range); j <= Mathf.Min(range, -i + range); j++)
            {
                var y = -(gridPosition.x + i) - gridPosition.z;
                Vector3 tile = new Vector3(gridPosition.x - i, y, gridPosition.z - j);

                Vector3 gridPos = CubeToAxial(tile);
                results.Add(gridPos);
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Does any one understand the range intersection guide, i am struggling to work out how to interpret it to write into code.

Hope some one can help.
Thanks

Comment: There's no question here. A list of things you want is not a question, and a list of things you don't understand is also not a question. What's your *specific* question?

Comment: Well i don't understand the logic in the guide to write it myself. Unless i try for ever and continue to not understand it, i might as well ask some one who may be able to understand it better so i can understand the logic of finding the intersecting tiles. Guess i'll ask a forum or something then.

Comment: "I don't understand" isn't a *question* that has an *answer*. Can you say *specifically* what you don't understand? This isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: No, i'll just ask some where else. Seems i rarely get answers on this site these days anyway. Is there a stack exchange specifically on computer algorithms if SO is not it? Perhaps they will be able to explain the algorithm logic if it is off topic here.

Comment: You might have better luck on the games site, since it seems like this question is about an algorithm that frequently occurs in games. But try to narrow down your question to a *specific* question that has an *answer*.

Comment: If you find that you are rarely getting answers to questions then the thing that is in common with all those cases is that *you* are the person who wrote a question that didn't get an answer. Maybe examine what it is about those questions that makes them hard to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how i can narrow down "I don't understand the algorithm". Since i have a working version but it uses 2 lists to compare. But this guide suggests a way to do it without that. But the pseudo code does not seem to suggest any form of intersection checks. So none of that guide seems to make much sense.

Comment: Well, you already did narrow down the question by suggesting that you what you don't understand is how to implement this without loops. How can you implement this without loops is a question (that is not really valid for this site unless you have some code that you present that isn't working). Your question would fit better in gamedev or math (since what you're really asking is why a regularly-shaped hex range is defined by it's x and y extremities).

Comment: I'll try the game dev stack exchange first then. Thanks :)

Comment: You say there is no intersection check in the code given on the site, but there is. The intersection check is in the computation of the max and min coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your confusion arises because you believe that the intersection algorithm is:

- Compute the members of the first set
- Compute the members of the second set
- Iterate over the members of one of the sets, discarding members that are not in the other
- The remaining members are in the intersection

That algorithm *works*, but it is not the algorithm that's presented, because that algorithm is too general. We can come up with a clever, faster algorithm.

Here, let's solve a simpler problem.

I'm going to give the start and end coordinates of a set of contiguous integers, so `(1->5)` means `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.  If we have `(a->b)` such that `b` is smaller than `a` then the set is empty.

What is the intersection of `(10->20)` and `(15->22)` ?

You could use your naive algorithm. The first set is `10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`, and the second is `15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22`, and we go through one set and say ok, 10, is that in the second set? No? Discard it. What about 11?  And going this way we could deduce through a long process that the answer is `15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`.

But there is an easier way. The intersection of `(a->b)` and `(c->d)` is `(max(a, c) -> min(b, d))`  So we take the bigger of the two first coordinates -- `15` -- and the smaller of the two second coordinates -- `20` -- and we get that the answer is `(15->20)`.

Now, can you do the same for *rectangles overlapping in a square grid*?

Now, can you do the same for *prisms overlapping in a cubic grid*?

You know that hex tiles can be seen as just a restriction on that set of unit cubes; the hex tiles are the cubic tiles whose coordinates sum to zero.

Now is it clear?

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Okay its simpler than i thought, thanks. I think i might need to research procedural generated code so i can take any number of regions and apply it to min and max. :)